# flutterアプリをchromebookに対応させる方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: flutter

私はflutterを使ってandroidアプリの開発をしています。
googleplayに載せているのですが、chromebook上では「このアイテムはお使いのデバイスに対応していません。」
と表示されます。
どのようにすればchromebookにインストールできるようになるのでしょうか。
因みに直接apkではインストールできます。

APIレベル　21+
対象SDK 31

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるかも。[\[Android\]「Chromebookでも使えるアプリ」にする](https://zenn.dev/m_coder/articles/article-zenn-chromebook-app), [ChromebookとAndroidアプリの互換性は？アプリインストールの手順まで徹底解説！](https://www.topgate.co.jp/chromebook-android)

Comment: ありがとうございます！